# How to make a python3 program (30 second timed loop) loop automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am attempting to make an offline (for now) looping security system. I am using a raspberryPi 4B and have gotten the recording function working (see code and output below).

How can I make the program loop without recompiling to make it record everything?

Basically the program will run the loop timed, and automatically restart infinitely. I can make the program run on boot so that is not a problem. I tried using a while true: with the timed loop in it and it hard crashed the program.

Secondary questions (stuff I can live without but would like to know how to do):

- How can I choose where the file is saved (currently saves on boot drive), mainly an external usb drive (will use usb connected sata SSD in future)
- How can I get the program to automatically overwrite the oldest footage without me doing anything?

Code:

```
#engineer:
#start date: 6/27/2023
#webcam test code from "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Exic9E5rNok"
#TLDR: this is based heavily on his tutorial up to the 19:19 ,mark
#once run, this will record video untill ended, then save it
#use this as base code, don't edit


import cv2
import time
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)#uses a specific video device, if multiple present change number

recording = True

Var = current_time + "Video_SCmk4.mp4"

frame_size = (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")#selects video codec and file type
out = cv2.VideoWriter(Var, fourcc, 14.0, frame_size)#output stream, the third variable xx.x is framerate


# timeout variable can be omitted, if you use specific value in the while condition
timeout = 5   # [seconds]

timeout_start = time.time()
while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Livestream", frame)
    out.write(frame)
    #if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):#end the stream
            #break
    
  
        
out.release()#saves the video
cap.release()#ends program use of camera
cv2.destroyAllWindows()#ends the videocapture
```

Output:

[image: Code Output]

################test code to get loop working###############

```
import time

# timeout variable can be omitted, if you use specific value in the while condition
timeout = 5   # [seconds]
while True:
    timeout_start = time.time()
    while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
        print("tic")
        
    print("break")
```

####output(testcode)###############
[test code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHZtR.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does that help clarify?

Comment: Please show the `while True:` program (full source code) and its crash error message.

Comment: I posted the test code that I am using to test the loops. I am doing this since I can only run the setup on my pi and not my laptop since setting up openCV is a nightmare on windows compared to raspbian OS 64bit. Note: when I add a one second wait to end, after the print break it doesn't crash.